# String message divide 10 character by character

Tags: java

I want to divide the following message by 10 character. I want to append every part into StringBuilder object.

```
    04421,1,13,S,312|4000004130,1;4000000491,1;4000005240,1;4000005789,2;4000004978,2;4000004934,2;4000004936,1;4000000569,2;4000005400,1;4000000;4000004934,2;
```

I have done the following solution :

```
    if(getMsgOtherPart(message) != null){      
         System.out.println("part message::"+getMsgOtherPart(message));
         String newMessage = getMsgOtherPart(message) ;

        int len = newMessage.length();
         System.out.println("len::"+len);
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int limit = 10;
        int lastIndex = 10;
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String completeMessage = null;
        for(int i = 0; i <= len;i++){
            count++;
            if( count == limit  && lastIndex < len){
                sb.append(getSmsUniqueHeader());
                sb.append(newMessage.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex));
                sb.append("#"); 
                sb.append("\n");                   
                firstIndex = lastIndex;
                lastIndex = firstIndex + limit;
                count = 0;
            } else if(count < limit && i == len)    {
                 System.out.println("lastIndex:: "+lastIndex);
                 sb.append(getSmsUniqueHeader());
                sb.append(newMessage.substring(lastIndex-10));
                sb.append("#"); 

            }               

        }
        completeMessage = sb.toString(); 
        System.out.println("message::\n"+completeMessage);
    }
```

I am getting output:

```
message::
$04421,1,13#
$,S,312|400#
$0004130,1;#
$4000000491#
$;400000540#
$0,1;400000#
$0;40000000#
$63,1;40000#
$00076,1;40#
$00000776,2#
$;400000078#
$8,2;400000#
------------
$0;#
```

Please let me know to optimize my solution.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that you want to arbitrarily divide that string by 10 characters?  Could you show us what the expected output is?

Comment: output is added

Comment: Is that your incorrect output? Can you instead show what you would like, please.

Comment: No. this is correct . But I need any optimization or other solution

Comment: @ken could you please post the full solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done this kind of thing in one of my project and here is the function i used, which return the List but you can modify it and use StringBuilder.

```
public List<String> splitStringEqually(String txtStr, int subStringSize) {
    List<String> splittedStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int start = 0; start < txtStr.length(); start += subStringSize) {

        splittedStringList.add(txtStr.substring(start, Math.min(txtStr.length(), start + subStringSize)));
    }
    return splittedStringList;
}
```

Comment: Could explain or link for substring(start, Math.min(txtStr.length(), start + subStringSize))

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library and use the Splitter class for this.

```
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: Splitter.fixedLength(10).split(message)){
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("#\n");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

String is maintained as char array internally. You can get the copy of that char array using `message.toCharArray()` and using a simple loop or java 8 streams pick elements in chunks of 10 and do whatever stuff you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basing heavily on [Rajen Raiyarela's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972100/1270789) and addressing the specific request from the OP, the code may look like this (upvote that one, not this one please!):

```
public String splitStringEqually(String txtStr, int subStringSize) {
    // Start off with the header
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("message::\n");

    int len = txtStr.length();
    for (int start = 0; start < len; start += subStringSize) {
        sb.append("$");
        // Copy the next 10 characters, or less if at end of string
        // Does not use txtStr.substring() as that creates an
        // unnecessary temporary string
        sb.append(txtStr, start, Math.min(len, start + subStringSize));
        sb.append("#\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

This can be called with simply:

```
String completeMessage = splitStringEqually(newMessage, limit);
```